# How can I make a set of surfaces level with an axis?

Tags: modeling

[image: What I have]

[image: Different Angle]

I want to make it so the selected surfaces/faces in the screenshot are level with the z-axis /completely flat on the x and y planes, I've tried to figure something out, but other than eyeballing it with the graph lines I don't really know what I could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes sure your Transform pivot point is set to Median Point.

Select the faces you want to flatten, Press S to bring up the scale tool, Then press Z, this will lock scaling to just the Z axis, finally press zero (not on the numpad).
This will scale the selected faces in the Z axis to zero (flat)

[image]